# How to manipulate values in LINQ query without "Explicit construction of entity type ### in query is not allowed when trying to modify value" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to change a field value from inside a LINQ select query for use in an ASP.NET MVC app?

For example, if a query returns a field with value "foo," I want it's output to be "bar" instead.

Essentially, I want LINQ to create this TSQL statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetSpecialCaseOfMyObject (
     @param varchar(10)
     ) AS

SELECT
     REPLACE( FieldA, 'foo', @param ) [FieldA]
     FieldB,
     FieldC
FROM
     MyTable
WHERE
     FieldA = @param
```

I've gotten this far, and it builds, but...

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> GetSpecialCaseOfMyObject (string myParam)
{
        var result = from o in Context.MyObject
                     where o.FieldA = myParam
                     select new MyObject
                        {
                                FieldA = o.FieldA.Replace("foo", myParam),
                                FieldB = o.FieldB,
                                FieldC = o.FieldC
                        };

        return result;
}
```

... when I try run a View to return data from it, I get a yellow screen of death:

> Explicit construction of entity type 'Model.DataAccess.MyObject' in query is not allowed.

I tried using an anonymous type, but then I can't cast it back to MyObject.

Is what I want to do possible without jumping through all kinds of hoops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be really easy if you had a domain model or even a view model.  You can use a tool like [AutoMapper](http://www.codeplex.com/AutoMapper) to handle most of the grunt work.  All you have to do is create a class that's similar to the entity model:

```
public class MyViewObject
{
    public MyViewObject(string fieldA, string fieldB, string fieldC)
    {
        this.FieldA = fieldA;
        this.FieldB = fieldB;
        this.FieldC = fieldC;
    }

    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    public string FieldC { get; set; }
}
```

And then map it (I'm showing a manual mapping here but as I said, you can automate a lot of this with a an automapping tool):

```
public IEnumerable<MyViewObject> GetViewObjects(string arg)
{
    var dataObjects = GetMyObjects(arg);
    return dataObjects.Select(o => TransformMyObject(o, "bar"));
}

public MyViewObject TransformMyObject(MyObject o, string fooReplacement)
{
    return new MyViewObject(o.FieldA, o.FieldB,
        o.FieldC.Replace("foo", fooReplacement);
}
```

This really isn't that much work and it will make it *a lot* easier to support future changes to the presentation logic.  It's also OK to have some of this logic in the view, if it's really simple formatting, but I prefer to keep views as dumb as possible, with View Models containing mostly (or entirely) string properties.

It may seem like "jumping through hoops" now, but once you have a separate domain and/or view model you will wonder how you ever got by without one.  When your app is missing an entire layer, you start to run into these odd leaky-abstraction issues.

Comment: I don't see it really as an abstraction issue - the app is architected out with separate DomainModel, Service, Controller, View layers and is using a Repository pattern, backended via Linq-To-SQL.  If I read from the database as is, I have no problem.  I can do unit testing with the MyObject object no problem.  I'm just unsure of how to manipulate the values as they come in without querying twice.

I'm still new to this method of doing things for sure, so maybe I'm just misunderstanding the obvious.

Comment: @Mike: If you already have a domain model then this transformation should be done during the mapping stage from the data model to the domain model (or from domain to view model).  You don't *need* to manipulate the values "as they come in" - you adjust them on the way *out*.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem - it all stemmed from a bad reference in my mapping process.  Once that was worked out, my initial code worked.  Your answers are what led me to go back and look at things again with a fine-toothed comb.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother modifying the query logic. It is the responsibility of the view to format the output. So leave the query as is:

```
public IQueryable<MyObject> GetMyObject (string myParam)
{
    return from o in Context.MyObject
           where o.FieldA = myParam
           select o;
}
```

and in your view format as necessary:

```
<div><%= Html.Encode(Model.FieldA.Replace("foo", "bar")) %></div>
```

or even better write a helper:

```
public static string FormatFieldA(this MyObject myObject)
{
    return myObject.FieldA.Replace("foo", "bar");
}
```

which could be used as:

```
<div><%= Html.Encode(Model.FormatFieldA()) %></div>
```

Comment: OK, but what if I want to do a replace using a variable instead of a literal, e.g., Replace("foo", myParam).  If I offload this to the View, I'd now need to pass in ViewData, right?  It just feels wrong to do that if there's any way to manipulate the data object itself and have the values I want bubble across to the View.